# Raise an event when an image in a SmallImageList of a ListView is clicked

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, events

I'm currently working on a VB.NET application (made with WinForms) which contains ListViews. I've set up in my ListViews a SmallImageList with an imageList, so each item of the ListView has an **Image** and some **text** displayed (checkboxes are disabled).

I would like to handle an event when I click on one of the images but NOT when I click on the text. Also I'd like to know which item is concerned. After some research I didn't find anything to help me. Maybe there's a work around to do in order to accomplish that.

Comment: Look into AddHandler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HitTest` method on the `ListView` to have it tell you which [ListViewHitTestLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestlocations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was hit.  One of the enumeration values is `ListViewHitTestLocations.Image`, which will tell you that the point sent to the function was on the listview item image.

```
Private Sub listView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim results = listView1.HitTest(e.Location)

    If results.Item IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", results.Item.Text, results.Location)
    End If

End Sub
```